# Offline map API for mobile development

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, maps

I am actually developing an iOS/Android application containing a map showing some places (like nearby places). I want to introduce a concept of offline map, in other words I want that the user can, when he is online, download the offline map (with the same informations contained on the online map).

The goal of this, is not having the map of the whole world or a continent, is just a city (New York for example) showing street's names and I can add annotations on it.

I don't really know from where to start to make this.

If someone has an idea, or already tried a good solution please let me know about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There are some non-Google tools which do offline mapping. I would suggest to take a look to [Nutiteq SDK](http://www.nutiteq.com/), if you use it with OpenStreetMap (including MapBox) then it is free, and it has all the features what Google has, including tilted/rotated map, and some extra features like 3D buildings and freedom to select any map source, including offline maps.

Disclosure: I'm working with Nutiteq.

Comment: According to https://developer.nutiteq.com/ there is no free support for offline maps at Nutiteq

Comment: Nutiteq has freemium model, just as everyone else here: some usage is free, but for real use it is not. In Nutiteq case we provide 60 days free period with the packages which include offline maps. If you want completely free service, and have unlimited free time, you'd can set up own server stack.

Answer (score 2):

For offline maps you might want to look at [Mapbox](http://mapbox.com). The mapbox.js API is easy to work with, even for front end developers/designers, and Mapbox serves [OpenStreetMap(OSM)](http://openstreetmap.org) tiles which are free to use. There are costs for hosting your map with Mapbox's map server but they're pretty reasonable. They also have an application called Mapbox Studio that you can use to custom design your maps to create the kinds of visual hierarchy, affordances, and brand standards that your app needs.Relatively easy implementation to IOS, with good documentation including ***offline*** use.

Answer (score 1):

Google Map provides caching inherently. But you can not have control over it. Also you cant pre bundle map details. User will have to access map functionality in online mode once then and then only it will become available. MapBox is the best SDK to show offline pre-bundled maps.